# Heebo Google Font - Special characters appearing strangely

Tags: html

I'm using Heebo Google fonts and commas and apostrophes appearing strangely in my HTML. As far as I know it only appears on desktop and not mobile.

Heebo is imported like this:

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:400,500,700,800|Fira+Sans:600" rel="stylesheet">
```

[image: Heebo font issue]
https://culturestride.com/

Comment: I have the same problem and I think it worked before. This seems to be a new error. We have to find a way to report this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a font problem that should be addressed here [github.com/google/fonts/issues](https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/2453)

Comment: Exactly, please just comment in the thread to make the devs know about this: https://github.com/google/fonts/issues/2453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed a few hours ago in the Google Fonts API. No changes need to be made.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by using the github version. I converted them to the Webfont versions using https://transfonter.org/. I added a font cache ([OMGF Wordpress Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/host-webfonts-local/)), disabled Google Fonts ([disable google fonts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-google-fonts/)) on my Wordpress,  then replaced these fonts (through cpanel). I know this is a temporary fix but it works. Working site: https://littlethiings.com. If someone, else finds a related fix please do update this forum. I created a css format for the font, you can call the included stylesheet and your font should work as intended (remove google font first). [Link](https://littlethiings.com/heebo-temporary-fix/) (scroll to bottom). Thanks!

**UPDATE**: The rollback has been completed. You can switch back to the google fonts again.

Answer (score 0):

## The cheapest solution to the problem

You can include all characters in Heebo font but not the `,`

Use this link tag for your font. I have included all characters of keyboard in it but not including those chars who are not working properly. As a result of which `,` will work in normal way and it does not look ugly.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Heebo:400,500,700,800|Fira+Sans:600&text=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz?.1234567890[]';.()/\!@#$%^&*-=+_{}:|\.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ*~\>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error from today in my website and i guess is a Google Font error.

Basically, what you need to do is to download an old version of the font, for example https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/heebo).
Then call again the font inside your local .css and not anymore through Google Api.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Heebo';
    src: url('Heebo-Regular.eot');
    src: url('Heebo-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('Heebo-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Heebo-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```